# Определить доступность узла локальной сети на bash

Tags: bash

Как можно правильно обработать башем например тот же вывод `fping` чтобы на выходе получить сабж - узел доступен или недоступен - с минимальной задержкой с момента запуска скрипта.
Погрешности в виде непрошедшего первого пинга не учитывать - сетка локальная.

Comment: установите fping. он как раз для этого и предназначен.

Comment: Хотелось бы иметь возможность организовать это без любых сторонних утилит, только средствами баша)

Comment: а обычный ping Вас тоже не устраивает?

Comment: 1) Только средствами `bash` это невозможно, сам по себе `bash` работать с сетью не умеет. 2) Что Вы подразумеваете под "доступностью узла"?

Comment: возможно я неточно описал свой вопрос :) отредактировал стартпост.

Comment: `fping ya.ru` - оно в консоль выведет состояние. А также выставит стандартную переменную `$?` равной нулю, если все узлы доступны (да, там список можно указать или маску подсети). Возвратит 1, если только часть узлов доступна и 2, если все недоступны. Если это локалка и хост доступен, то работает очень быстро.

Comment: Пинг с помощью одного пакета, например: `ping -c1 <host> > /dev/null && echo "host is UP" || echo "host is DOWN"`

Comment: @approximatenumber, да, именно то что нужно) Оформите ваш пост - отдельным ответом, плюсану)

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать утилиту `ping`, посылая один пакет (`-c1`) для проверки доступности узла. В зависимости от возвращаемого значения выхода утилиты можно сигнализировать об доступности или недоступности узла. Например:

```
host="192.168.222.222"
ping -c1 "$host" > /dev/null && echo ""$host" is UP" || echo ""$host" is DOWN"
```

Comment: "Погрешности в виде непрошедшего первого пинга не учитывать - сетка локальная." - одного пакета маловато будет для такого требования.

Comment: @edem в таком случае придется добавлять по одному пакету, пока ясность не будет достигнута :) 
на самом деле, если серьезно, в случае временного отсутствия ICMP-ответов хорошо бы подумать о причинах такого явления

Comment: @edem, можно посылать больше пакетов. насколько я помню, логика формирования кода возврата у программы *ping* такова, что ноль вернётся и в том случае, если получен хотя бы один ответ.